# Retirar arquivo especifico de input multiple type="file"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Fiz um input da seguinte maneira:

```
<input type="file" id="arquivos" name='arquivos[]' multiple onchange="funcao_listar()">
```

Onde após clicar no botão e selecionar os diversos arquivos para upload ele lista o arquivo com o botão de deletar ao lado de acordo com a figura (figura apenas para ilustrar).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para retirar um arquivo específico do input quando clicar no ícone para deletar? Deixando esclarecido que não é apenas retirar o item de visualização mas sim retirar do input para quando for clicado em submit não ser feito o upload do mesmo.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no seguinte [link do SoEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144419/how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-filelist), acredito que possa lhe ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Creio que não seja possível fazer esta remoção de apenas um item ou alguns específicos. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist

> The HTMLInputElement interface [HTML5] has a readonly FileList
>   attribute, […]

Porém, é possível resetar a lista por inteiro com o código:

```
document.getElementById('arquivos').value = "";
```

Comment: No caso então é possível limpar a lista de arquivos do input e adicionar uma nova lista mas sem o item selecionado para exclusão, dando a impressão de que o mesmo foi excluído? 

Para este caso a lista seria copiada em outra variável (ou objeto, ou array), limpado o input e depois a lista copiada adicionada mas sem o item selecionado para a exclusão.

Caso seja possível fazer isso, como faço para adicionar arquivos no input? No caso esta lista copiada.

Comment: @AndersonBrunelModolon creio que não é possível adicionar a nova lista. O FileList é readonly, 
Acho mais fácil você manter uma lista separada e tratar isso no serverside. Porém, acho que o esforço não compensa. Colocar um botão limpar tudo e diz pra o usuário parar de ser preguiçoso. Rsrsrsrs

Answer (score 1):

A lista de arquivos no `<input type="file" multiple>`  é somente leitura, porém você pode manter uma lista separada para manipular os arquivos conforme a seguir. Fonte do [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133956/4312593)

**Exemplo**

```js
var dropZoneId = "drop-zone";
var buttonId = "clickHere";
var mouseOverClass = "mouse-over";
var dropZone = $("#" + dropZoneId);
var inputFile = dropZone.find("input");
var finalFiles = {};
$(function() {



  var ooleft = dropZone.offset().left;
  var ooright = dropZone.outerWidth() + ooleft;
  var ootop = dropZone.offset().top;
  var oobottom = dropZone.outerHeight() + ootop;

  document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    dropZone.addClass(mouseOverClass);
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;

    if (!(x < ooleft || x > ooright || y < ootop || y > oobottom)) {
      inputFile.offset({
        top: y - 15,
        left: x - 100
      });
    } else {
      inputFile.offset({
        top: -400,
        left: -400
      });
    }

  }, true);

  if (buttonId != "") {
    var clickZone = $("#" + buttonId);

    var oleft = clickZone.offset().left;
    var oright = clickZone.outerWidth() + oleft;
    var otop = clickZone.offset().top;
    var obottom = clickZone.outerHeight() + otop;

    $("#" + buttonId).mousemove(function(e) {
      var x = e.pageX;
      var y = e.pageY;
      if (!(x < oleft || x > oright || y < otop || y > obottom)) {
        inputFile.offset({
          top: y - 15,
          left: x - 160
        });
      } else {
        inputFile.offset({
          top: -400,
          left: -400
        });
      }
    });
  }

  document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    $("#" + dropZoneId).removeClass(mouseOverClass);
  }, true);


  inputFile.on('change', function(e) {
    finalFiles = {};
    $('#filename').html("");
    var fileNum = this.files.length,
      initial = 0,
      counter = 0;

    $.each(this.files, function(idx, elm) {
      finalFiles[idx] = elm;
    });

    for (initial; initial < fileNum; initial++) {
      counter = counter + 1;
      $('#filename').append('<div id="file_' + initial + '"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-file fa-stack-1x "></i><strong class="fa-stack-1x" style="color:#FFF; font-size:12px; margin-top:2px;">' + counter + '</strong></span> ' + this.files[initial].name + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg closeBtn" onclick="removeLine(this)" title="remove"></span></div>');
    }
  });



})

function removeLine(obj) {
  inputFile.val('');
  var jqObj = $(obj);
  var container = jqObj.closest('div');
  var index = container.attr("id").split('_')[1];
  container.remove();

  delete finalFiles[index];
  //console.log(finalFiles);
}
```

```css
#drop-zone {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 3px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #7E7E7E;
}

#drop-zone input {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}


/*Important*/

#drop-zone.mouse-over {
  border: 3px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: #7E7E7E;
}


/*If you dont want the button*/

#clickHere {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4679BD;
  padding: 10px;
}

#clickHere:hover {
  background-color: #376199;
}

#filename {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.file-preview {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.closeBtn:hover {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}


}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop-zone">
  <p>Drop files here...</p>
  <div id="clickHere">or click here.. <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple />
  </div>
  <div id='filename'></div>
</div>
```